# Why django test --keep-db works with postgres database but not with default sqlite3

Tags: django, postgresql, testing, sqlite

I'm testing Django (v1.11.4) application in two setups of database:
1) postgres database running in docker container
or
2) sqlite3 as (default database)

When running tests with `--keepdb` option I observe different behavior for these two setups: for postgres `--keepdb` works as expected (there is no database creation and running test is fast) but for sqlite3 database `--keepdb` seems not working (for each run of the test there is creation of database).
Is it possible to have `--keepdb` working with sqlite3? If so any idea what settings might affect behavior described as above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, [Django uses an in-memory database when testing sqlite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database). This means that the test database isn't persistent. You can override this behaviour in your `DATABASES` setting by specifying a test name:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite',
        'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'testdb.sqlite3',
        },
    },
}
```